# Fix CVEs in Log4j 1.x

Tags: log4j

Maybe a naive question. but many projects still use Log4j 1.x
Is there no possibility to fix at least the CVE's in Log4j 1.x? It is clear that every project should switch to log4j2. But that doesn't change the fact that the smaller security leaks in Log4j 1.x are there, even if less critical.

It it possible that the community of Log4j maybe describes how to use Log4j 1.x to be more secure. e.g. not to use some of the appenders?

Answer (score 2):

The development of log4j is volunteer based. There simply aren't enough volunteers to keep maintaining all legacy applications.

And even if there is some volunteer that patches log4j 1.2 (=latest), it is still a deprecated version that is not up-to-date in many other ways (has not been updated for 6 years). Everybody should really migrate to log4j2.

[Read this blog post from Apache](https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_logging_services_project_announces)